# Decrypt binary file(image) with crypto-js

Tags: image, encryption, binary, cryptography, cryptojs

So the question is how to decrypt binary files with crypto-js. When I try to encrypt/decrypt json -> that I convert into base64 all is okey, but how to decrypt binary files like this
[screenshot of data that is representing image in bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNkKP.png)

Comment: If you only have the data then the chance to decrypt it is next to zero. Reverse engineer the code that generate or processes this data to understand it's data format.

Comment: Encryption always works with binary data, so the "string" encryption Just converts the string into binaray and after decryption back to a string. Just leave out the string conversions, read the image as binary from the file, decrypt it and write the data back to another file.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I need to decrypt data with aes 128 algorithm, I have key and iv for it. I mean need help with the code how to do that.

Comment: As Stackoverflow is not a code writing service you should search for "crypto-js aes file encryption" and try to solve your problem. If you are still struggling with some code please come back with your specific problem, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelFehr and may be do you know, when I get wordArray after decrypting with negative sigBytes, like sigBytes: -24, what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in data itself, should fetch image like **arraybuffer**, because just response.data had strange encoding. Question can be closed.

```
fetch(url)
 .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
 .then(buffer => {
    const decrypted = decryptImg(buffer, key, iv)
});
```